# Kivy Python- Text Input Box Filling Entire Float Layout Screen

Tags: python, kivy, textinput, kivy-language

I am running into an issue with TextInput in Kivy.

When I add it to the existing `FloatLayout` on one of my screens it takes up the entire window, even with a height specified. I'd like to keep this in the .py file, so please refrain from adding any styling options for sizing in a .kv file.

```
class WebsiteInput(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(WebsiteInput, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self._finish_init)

    def _finish_init(self, dt):
        # Title Label
        self.lbl1 = Label(text="Enter a URL to bind to this button:", pos=(self.x, self.height +132))
        self.lbl1.font_name = 'Montserrat-Bold.ttf'
        self.lbl1.font_size = 28
        self.ids.float_web.add_widget(self.lbl1)
        # URL Text Input
        self.web_input = TextInput(height=100)
        self.web_input.height = 100
        self.ids.float_web.add_widget(self.web_input)
```

As you can see I have tried affecting the size in two different locations, and it is still filling the entire window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `size` property to take effect you need the [`size_hint`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.layout.html#understanding-the-size-hint-property-in-widget) property to be `None` on the corresponding axis:

```
class WebsiteInput(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(WebsiteInput, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self._finish_init)

    def _finish_init(self, dt):
        # Title Label
        self.lbl1 = Label(text="Enter a URL to bind to this button:",
                          pos=(self.x, self.height +132))
        self.lbl1.font_name = 'Montserrat-Bold.ttf'
        self.lbl1.font_size = 28
        self.ids.float_web.add_widget(self.lbl1)
        # URL Text Input
        self.web_input = TextInput(height=100, 
                                   size_hint = (1,  None))
        self.ids.float_web.add_widget(self.web_input)
```

Comment: Can you tell me the difference between size and size_hint? Is it not redundant?

Comment: @Austin it is not redundant, `size` indicates an **absolute** size in pixels. On the other hand, `size_hint` indicates the size but **relative** to the parent size, it´s a fraction of the parent size (range 0 to 1). With size the widget always has the same size, with `size_hint`, if the parent grows, the child grows to maintain the proportion. In your case, if you resize the window, TextInput height will always be 100 but the width will increase to occupy the entire FloatLayout width (1 = 100%).